# mac tunnelblick error: --auth-user-pass fails for No such file or directory

Tags: mac, tunnelblick

both `.ovpn` file and `namepassword.txt` are located at `/User/tiina/Downloads/OpenVPN/configs`. And the last statement in .ovpn is `auth-user-pass namepassword.txt` However, tunnelclick log shows:

```
Options error: --auth-user-pass fails with 'author-keys.txt': No such file or directory
Options error: Please correct these errors.
Use --help for more information.
```

Answer (score 0):

Make a folder called "configuration" or any name you prefer. Put those .ovpn and .txt files in there together and rename the folder to configuration.tlbk.

You should now have a working Tunnelblick configuration file.